# Track Application Usage in .NET Application

Tags: c#, .net, tracking, trace, rich-client-platform

I have a.NET (C#) WPF application which run on different clients.
I would like to track the usages, metrics, error, etc. of the application (with the clients permission off course) and have this information be sent back for further analysis.

I'm talking something like Google Analytics but for a client application and not web site.

I'm currently looking for very basic stuff like errors and crashes of the application, application start, application exit and because my application is build with navigation (not SDI or MDI) when a screen is navigated to and when navigated away.

Because this is a client application, and some clients are not always connected to the internet I think I'll have to cache the data and send it once connection exists.

1. Has anyone seen something like this (that cost less then 100$) ?
2. Do anyone else is interested in such ability?

Thank you very much,
Ido.

Comment: If you are still interested in tracking (2 years later :) ) - I have created such a tracking tool and search for beta users

Comment: Sorry, I've moved on. I actually use Google Analytics to treat the application like web app with each screen has a specific URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I developed something that basically did what you want on a project once. I just used an AOP library (I think I used PostSharp but there are quite a few libraries out there now that are free) that tracked when a form was opened/closed, when errors were thrown, etc. We just stored the info in a text file which was uploaded to an FTP server when the application was started the next time. We mostly used it for error reports (it only sent if the application crashed) but you could do something like that for metrics gathering purposes.

Comment: Have you published this library? They idea is clear, I'm looking for implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately it was for a client who wouldn't let me open source it. That being said, something like this: http://runtimeintelligence.codeplex.com/ might work. Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like good project. I'll look into it with more detail hopefully it will be the one I need.